Who does the prophecy in Malachi refer to?
Malachi 3:1:

הִנְנִ֤י שֹׁלֵ֙חַ֙ מַלְאָכִ֔י וּפִנָּה־דֶ֖רֶךְ לְפָנָ֑י וּפִתְאֹם֩ יָב֨וֹא אֶל־הֵיכָל֜וֹ הָאָד֣וֹן ׀ אֲשֶׁר־אַתֶּ֣ם מְבַקְשִׁ֗ים וּמַלְאַ֨ךְ הַבְּרִ֜ית אֲשֶׁר־אַתֶּ֤ם חֲפֵצִים֙ הִנֵּה־בָ֔א אָמַ֖ר יְהֹוָ֥ה צְבָאֽוֹת׃
Behold, I am sending My messenger to clear the way before Me, and the Sovereign you seek shall come to the temple suddenly. As for the angel of the covenant that you desire, he is already coming.

Who is "My messenger"? (Elijah?)  Who is "the Sovereign you seek"?  (The Messiah?)  Who is "the angel of the covenant"?

Not the answer but is there some kind of play on words here as this is the book of מַלְאָכִ֔י?

A few possibilities...
Note the Ibn Ezra, he suggests the messenger could possibly be Moshiach ben Yosef.
The Metzudos Dovid provides a definitive rundown. He suggests the messenger to be a "מלאך מן השמים" - an angel from heaven, and he will clear the way before G-d. He will cut off from the world the sinners and the rebels, before Hashem purifies the land with His Shechinah.
As far as the Sovereign, he writes:

זהו מלך המשיח אשר עין כל אדם מצפה ומייחל לו ומבקש ביאתו
This is the Messianic King whom the eye of every man expects and longs for and longs for his coming

And the malach habris is a reference to Eliyahu.

To complicate matters, "my messenger" in Hebrew is...  Malachi!  Is the prophet referring to himself?
